# WebSocket with angular universal

Tags: node.js, angular, express, websocket, angular-universal

I'm trying to add websockets to a server that's using angular universal. As far as I can tell, express is consuming my request before it gets to my sockets, but I could be wrong about that.

I get this error in chrome:
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4200/socket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response`

and I get this error in firefox:
`Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:4200/socket.`

when I run a separate nodejs server without the angular code, the websockets work fine.

Here is the relevant part of my server.ts

```js
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node'

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine'
import * as express from 'express'
import { join } from 'path'

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server'
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common'
import { existsSync } from 'fs'

import * as WebSocket from 'ws'

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express()
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/CAHClone/browser')
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index'

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }))

  server.set('view engine', 'html')
  server.set('views', distFolder)

  server.use(express.json())

  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }))

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.url === '/socket') return next() // leave '/socket' open for the websockets
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] })
  })

  return server
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000

  // Start up the Node server
  const expressApp = app()

  const server = expressApp.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })

  // Websockets
  const wss = setupWebsockets(server)
}

function setupWebsockets(server) {
  const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server, path: '/socket' })
  
  wss.on('connection', ws => {
    console.log('Client connected.')
    ws.send({message: 'Hi there!'})
  })
  
  wss.on('message', msg => {
    console.log('Client said: ' + msg.toString())
  })

  return wss
}

declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || ''
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run()
}

export * from './src/main.server'
```

And here is a server.js file that works without angular related code

```js
const express = require('express')
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const { join } = require('path')
const { existsSync } = require('fs')

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
function app() {
  const server = express()

  server.use(express.json())

  server.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.url === '/socket') return next()
    res.end('Hello, world!')
  })

  return server
}

function setupWebsockets(server) {
  const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server, path: '/socket' })
  console.log('set up websocket server');

  wss.on('connection', ws => {
    console.log('Client connected.');
    ws.send('Hi there!')
  })

  wss.on('message', msg => {
    console.log('Client said: ' + msg.toString());
  })
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000

  const expressApp = app()

  const server = expressApp.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })

  // Websockets
  const wsServer = setupWebsockets(server)
}

run()
```

Could anyone help me understand what part of angular universal is breaking my websockets, and how to fix it?

Comment: Your trying to connect to port 4200.. but your servers seems to be running on 4000..?

Comment: @MikeOne Thanks, but I don't think that's the issue, angular seems to set the process.port.env to 4200 when I run it with `npm run dev:srr`. I'll take a closer look at the ports though to see if there's anything wrong there. For the JS server I am intentionally using 4000 and I do connect to it when testing.

Comment: The issue actually does seem to be port related. Angular is using what seems to be a random port as well as 4200, and the websockets work on this random port but not on 4200. I will continue to investigate, but if anyone has more info about how this works please let me know.

Comment: Update: this works fine is I run `npm run build:ssr` followed by `npm run serve:ssr`, the issue seems to be with the dev environment set up with `npm run dev:ssr`

Comment: Why aren't you using something similar to `SupplyData` (for .NET, node should have smth similar) instead of using another websocket back to your server?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with the 'ws' module and passing in an express server. Try creating your server with the 'http' module and pass it into both express and 'ws'.  I also recommend taking care of any authorization that you are going to do in the 'upgrade' event if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve the matter with dev:ssr ?

It is indeed working fine with `serve:ssr` but the only way I made it work with `dev:ssr` in local development is by using a proxy from `ws://localhost:4200/ws` to `ws://localhost:4000`

```json
{
  "/ws": {
    "target": "ws://localhost:4000",
    "secure": false,
    "ws": true
  }
}
```

Se my question here : [Angular Universal (ssr-dev-server) Setting or getting the random port of the express app in dev:ssr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73766367/angular-universal-ssr-dev-server-setting-or-getting-the-random-port-of-the-exp)