# Angular Universal (ssr-dev-server) Setting or getting the random port of the express app in dev:ssr

Tags: angular, express, websocket, port, universal

I am trying to call a websocket server in an express app in Angular Universal.

---

It works fine in production when using `npm run serve:ssr`

```
> my-app@0.0.0 serve:ssr
> node dist/evaluator/server/main.js

Node Express app listening on http://localhost:4000
```

I can call the websocket at `ws://localhost:4000`

---

However in local development mode with `npm run dev:ssr`

This following line of code in the builder

https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/main/modules/builders/src/ssr-dev-server/utils.ts#L22

```js
export function getAvailablePort(): Promise<number> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const server = createServer();
    server
      .unref()
      .on('error', reject)
      .listen(0, () => {
        const { port } = server.address() as AddressInfo;
        server.close(() => resolve(port)); // This port is random
      });
  });
}
```

sets a random port  affecting on the fly `process.env['PORT']` for the express server (SSR).

code in server.ts (express server side)

```js
export function app(): express.Express {
  const express_app = express();
  // ....
  return express_app;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000; // that process port comes from the above builder utils

  // Start up the Node app
  const express_app = app();
  const server = http.createServer(express_app);
  const wss = new WebSocketServer({ server });

  wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    ws.on('message', (message) => {
      ws.send(JSON.stringify('mess ' + message));
    });
  });
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express app listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}
```

This comment states that you can set the port by config

https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1628#issuecomment-616322722

but it seems to me that there is a confusion with the angular default 4200 port (that you can set in angular.json, as states the doc https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/main/modules/builders/README.md#ssr-dev-server) but it does not affect the express server port which is always random.

If I force the port to 4000 in /node_modules/@nguniversal/builders/src/ssr-dev-server/utils.jsL27 then the express app starts on port 4000 then I can proxy the request in proxy.conf.json with for instance

```json
{
  "/ws": {
    "target": "ws://localhost:4000",
    "secure": false,
    "ws": true
  }
}
```

otherwise I don't know how I can get that dynamic port to request the websocket. It seems the proxy magic af Angular Universal only proxy `http://localhost:4200/` to the express router and not `ws://localhost:4200/` also. So the only way I can request the websocket is by proxying `ws://localhost:4200/ws` to `ws://localhost:4000/`

My code in app.component.ts (angular frontend side)

```js
  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: InjectionToken<Record<string, unknown>>,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
  ) {
    this.window = this.document.defaultView as Window;
    if (this.isBrowser) {
      const myWebSocket = webSocket(this.window.location.href.replace('http', 'ws')); 
    
    // open a socket to ws://localhost:4200/

    // so here the PORT is not correct ws://localhost:4200/ does not reply 
    // because the port is dynamicaly set unless I hard fix it to 4000 in utils 
    // and set it here too instead of Angular 4200 port

      myWebSocket.asObservable().subscribe(dataFromServer => {
        console.log(dataFromServer);
      });
      myWebSocket.next(JSON.stringify({}));
    }
```

My question is how can I set this port or how can get this dynamic process.env['PORT'] on angular side ?

```
Compiled successfully.
Node Express app listening on http://localhost:43481 // How can I set this port ? or how can I get it in app component

** Angular Universal Live Development Server is listening on http://localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
```

Related :

[WebSocket with angular universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65315284/websocket-with-angular-universal)

https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1848

https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1722

Thanks for reading

Comment: Try not to establish websockets during ssr. The data you need is in the database right next to the script invoking the `main.server.ts`. In .NET we can use something like `SupplyData` to get data from the database and pass it to the bootmodule during SSR

Comment: Thanks @Pieterjan but I don't have a database right now. My Websocket sends an url from the ssr site to the backend and the backend opens Pupppeteer and fetch the site. The issues is only the random port from https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/main/modules/builders/src/ssr-dev-server/utils.ts#L22 in dev mode.

Comment: I see. Perhaps you can do something similar as .NET SSR does. The javascript [prints a line to the console with the port in it](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.NodeServices/Content/Node/entrypoint-http.js#L178). Then .NET [reads the lines from the console, and checks them against a regex](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.NodeServices/HostingModels/HttpNodeInstance.cs#L122)

Comment: But I don't know if you're in a situation to change/replace this nguniversal script... You can attempt to create a PR on the repo

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this today, and indeed this is very upsetting. The way I solve this is to create another server (wss) on `development`, but use the same server as express server on `production`:

```
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const app = await init();
  const server = createServer(app);

  // Initialize WebSocket server
  initWSS(server);

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
    // console.log('Node Express server listening on http://localhost:', port);
  });
```

This is the `initWSS`:

```
export const initWSS = (server: Server) => {
  const env = process.env['NODE_ENV'];

  if(env === 'production') wss = new WebSocketServer({ server });
  else wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 4202 });
  ...
```

So if the environment is `development` then create another wss server and assign it into a fixed port (4202 for wss, 4201 for the main server) in my case. Else, just join the express and wss server into the `process.env['PORT']` at production.